# optional parameters in routes defined through annotations

Tags: symfony

is there a more elegant way to define optional parameters in annotated routes then to define 2 annotations?

Here's how I did it:

```
/**
*
* @Route("/view/{lang}/{file}", name="legacy_translation_view_file")
* @Route("/view/{lang}", name="legacy_translation_view")
* @Template()
*/
public function viewAction($lang,$file=null)
{
   ...
}
```

i've seen that the annotation class has a field named "defaults" but am not quiet sure about the syntax

thx

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Symfony has a page on [@Route](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html):

E.g maybe you can try.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/{lang}/{file}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"file" = null})
 */
public function showAction($id, $lang, $file)
{
}
```

If null doesn't work try an empty string.

Comment: as allways it's only a matter of knowing where to find the information. i have never before looked into the bundle reference. thx

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing.. but if you have multiple null or empty string defaults it creates paths like /1/en///1234/23 and Symfony complains about no matching route.