# @Route annotation, optional parameter is not optional

Tags: routes, annotations, symfony

I've annotated a Symfony3 controller method with a route that should take an optional parameter in the last position.  If I attempt to generate the route without the last parameter, I either get a route that looks like what I want but doesn't work (fos-js-routing) or I fail to generate a route (twig). I'm hoping there's just a typo in my @Route annotation, but I can't see it.  Here's the code.

The route does work if both parameters are supplied.

### controller method:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/new/{format_id}/{room_id}", name="ci_item_new", requirements={"format_id"="\d+"}, options={"expose"=true})
     * @ParamConverter("format", options={"id" = "format_id"})
     * @ParamConverter("room", options={"id" = "room_id"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param SupplyFormat
     * @param Room|null
     * @return array
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, SupplyFormat $format, Room $room = null)
    {
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setFormat($format);
        if($room) $item->setRoom($room);
...
    }
```

### fos:js-routing call:

```
Routing.generate('ci_item_new', {'format_id': data.format.id})
```

### route generated:

https://example.com/web/app_dev.php/item/new/2205 <- observed == expected

### error message when trying url

No route found for "GET /item/new/2205" (from "https://example.com/web/app_dev.php/supply/show/1)

---

### twig routing call:

```
{{ path('ci_item_new', {'format_id': supply.formats[0]}) }}
```

### no route generated

### error message

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("room_id") to generate a URL for route "ci_item_new".").

---

Any ideas why my @Route annotation doesn't work? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983264/optional-parameters-in-routes-defined-through-annotations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078154/route-with-optional-parameter-is-not-working-in-symfony-2) and a pile of others without finding what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the parameters in your function parameters as well, and use the same name and then you don't need the @ParamConverter. Also, you need to specify the defaults to avoid the optional paramters not being passed. So this would be your changes:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new/{format_id}/{room_id}",
 *      defaults={"format_id" = 0, "room_id" = 0},
 *      name="ci_item_new",
 *      requirements={"format_id"="\d+"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param SupplyFormat
 * @param Room|null
 * @return array
 */
public function newAction($format_id, $room_id, Request $request)
{
    $item = new Item();
    $item->setFormat($format_id);
    if($room_id) $item->setRoom($room_id);
...
}
```

I think that should work for you, but I haven't tried it.

Obviously, you'll need to check the parameters if they are 0 and so on...

Comment: The reason that the Parameter Converter is used is so that I get automatic object hydration. Since the PK of both objects is `id` and Route needs 2 different variable names, I have to specifically map them. 2nd, setting `Room $room=null` is supposed to be the same as setting the default in the Route (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18694177/128245 ).

Comment: Hi dnagirl. You do know that the PK of an Entity can be set using the `@ORM\Column(name="format_id", type="integer")` notation? I use that in all my entities so that they are all not named 'id", and so that they are unique and I know what they represent. I wasn't aware you needed hydration.

Comment: Hi Alvin. I used to set all my PKs as you suggest. But the "auto-magic" of the convention is too pervasive. I've run across cases where not using 'id' is far more work than succumbing and using it. Sadly, this particular case is the opposite.